# How to move a file on Amazon S3 to another bucket using Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, amazon-s3

I'd like to copy a file that's already on S3 to another bucket using the Zend Framework and without having to copy the file to the local filesystem first.

How can this be achieved?

If copying to another bucket is not possible, is it possible to just make a copy of an object (without having to copy the file to the local filesystem)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon S3 allows you to copy an object between buckets and to create a copy of the object in the same bucket using the `PUT copy` call - http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/index.html?RESTObjectCOPY.html

To create the object copy using Zend Framework you can use the `copyObject` method in `Zend_Service_Amazon_S3`